# Mapping списка объектов как списка ID

Tags: java

Есть класс пользователя и группы.

```
@Entity
class User {
    private Set<Club> clubs;
    // other props. and getters/setters
}

@Entity
class Club {
    private Long id;
    // other props. and getters/setters
}
```

Пользователь может быть в нескольких группах, но в DTO должны быть только id этих групп.

```
class UserMainDto {
    private Set<Long> clubIds;
    // other props. and getters/setters
}
```

Контроллер:

```
return new ModelMapper().modelMapper.map(user, UserMainDto.class);
```

На выходе ожидаю, что у пользователя будет массив из id групп, но свойстро clubIds всегда null. Что я делаю не так?